# Full size images from Google Image Search cache

Tags: google, image-search

Due to a crash I have lost some images from my website. These are all in Google Image search, but they are all scaled down. Does anybody know if there is a way to recover the full images?

I have tried the Wayback Machine and Bing, but neither has the images I need unfortunately.

Comment: Have you searched the exact URL in Google search?

Answer (score 2):

Who is your host provider? Almost always they have backup versions of your website. In some cases they may charge you, specially if its for specific files, but you may be able to download the whole website backed up for free. Contact them for better assistance.
In regards to your question, I really don't know.

Comment: unfortunately this is not an option :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all BACKUP BACKUP BACKUP.
Try TinEye with the low quality pics you save from Google-images and you might just get lucky they also saved it.